# Why is a subsection of my range failing to add borders (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, border, aspose, named-ranges, aspose-cells

Based on code from [here](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/819795.aspx), I added the following:

```
string bottomRightRange = string.Format("F{0}", rowsUsed);
var range = locationWorksheet.Cells.CreateRange("A8", bottomRightRange);

//Setting border for each cell in the range
var style = workBook.CreateStyle();
style.SetBorder(BorderType.BottomBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
style.SetBorder(BorderType.LeftBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
style.SetBorder(BorderType.RightBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
style.SetBorder(BorderType.TopBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);

for (int r = range.FirstRow; r < range.RowCount; r++)
{
    for (int c = range.FirstColumn; c < range.ColumnCount; c++)
    {
        Cell cell = locationWorksheet.Cells[r, c];
        cell.SetStyle(style, new StyleFlag()
        {
            TopBorder = true,
            BottomBorder = true,
            LeftBorder = true,
            RightBorder = true

        });
    }
}

//Setting outline border to range
range.SetOutlineBorder(BorderType.TopBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
range.SetOutlineBorder(BorderType.BottomBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
range.SetOutlineBorder(BorderType.LeftBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
range.SetOutlineBorder(BorderType.RightBorder, CellBorderType.Thin, Color.Black);
```

That worked well - for the most part - but notice this:

[image]

The last seven rows at the end (except for bottom border on the last row, and the right border for all of them) are not borderized. Why not?

NOTE: *bottomRightRange* equates to "F94" in this case.

Why would a big chunk work right, then a small portion at the end not work as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was (not obvious from the code above) that the sheet has a few preliminary rows used as header information. These have to be taken into account when looping. So this:

```
for (int r = range.FirstRow; r < range.RowCount; r++)
```

...needs to become this:

```
for (int r = range.FirstRow; r < range.RowCount + FUDGE_FACTOR; r++`)
```

FUDGE_FACTOR is the number of rows used before the "real" data commences.